# using jQuery to animate text in an input field

Tags: jquery, textbox, jquery-animate

I have an input text field which contains the text "Search the website..." as its default value.

When the user clicks on it, the text fades to a blank box, ready for the search query.

When the user clicks out, the default text fades back in.

This works fine but the only problem is the whole input field is fading with the BORDER and BACKGROUND included. So my question is:

Is it possible to animate just the text?

Here is the code which makes it happen:

```
        <fieldset id="siteSearch">
            <input type="text" class="siteSearchField" value="Search the website..." maxlength="50"><input type="image" class="siteSearchBtn" src="header_search_btn.gif" alt="search">
            <script>
                var defaultText = $('.siteSearchField').val();
                $('.siteSearchField')
                .focus
                (
                    function()
                    {
                        $(this)
                        .animate
                        (
                            {'opacity': 0}, 287,
                                function()
                                {
                                    $(this).val('');
                                }
                        )
                        .animate
                        (
                            {'opacity': 1}, 287
                        );
                    }
                )
                .focusout
                (
                    function()
                    {
                        $(this)
                        .animate
                        (
                            {'opacity': 0}, 287,
                                function()
                                {
                                    $(this).val(defaultText);
                                }
                        )
                        .animate
                        (
                            {'opacity': 1}, 287
                        );
                    }
                );
            </script>
        </fieldset>
```

I am relatively new to jQuery so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your  text field in a div and style it to look like input, while leaving  without background and without border.

Comment: I cannot get this to work. it is still animating the parent element

Answer (score 0):

You can animate your text color to make it the same color as your background using [jQuery Color plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/), instead of animating opacity. See plugin [DEMO](http://jqueryui.com/animate/)

Answer (score 0):

Side stepping your original question : it looks like you are trying to reimplement an existing feature :

```
<input type="search" placeholder="Search the website ..." />
```

The `placeholder` attribute is mostly supported in recent browsers (IE 9 and less doesn't support it, IE 10 and other browsers do), and you can use an existing javascript plugin to add the functionality to older browsers.

See : [Html5Please : input[placeholder]](http://html5please.com/#placeholder)

Polyfill plugin : [GitHub : jquery-placeolder](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder)

Comment: I tried animating the placeholder but this still animates the border of the input element

Comment: I don't understand your comment. My suggestion is : drop your javascript code, and use the `placeholder` attribute on your input. If you want support for IE 9 and less, add the mentioned plugin, which should seamlessly add the functionality on your page (using javascript, instead of built-in browser functions).

Comment: Sorry - I meant I tried that. I used `<input type="text" placeholder="Enter search query...">` and adjusted the JS, but the border was still animating. Although this attribute does have the functionality I was looking for, and thankyou for introducing it to me, it does not include fading animations. I just don't understand why animating `val()` affects parent nodes in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

In your code :

```
$(this).animate( {'opacity': 0}, 287, /*callback*/ );
```

will animate the whole input field (along with its borders).

You want to have *something* that fades in/fades out, and *something else*, which draws the borders, that never moves.

On way to do this :

- put your `input` inside a `span`
- put the borders on the `span`, remove all borders from the `input`
- keep your current `focusin / focusout` handlers